# What is a CIM motor?

Tags: motor

I'm trying to make decisions for motors on a robot build. I keep running across CIM Motors. What is a CIM Motor? Where does the designation CIM come from? What does CIM mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCL Industrial Motors according to [this thread](http://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/showthread.php?t=110767). So CIM is an acronym for the manufacturer of one of the motors the FIRST guys use. The term seems to have been generalized in that community to mean a big powerful motor in their context. Outside of FIRST/VEX the acronym has no meaning.

It's a DC motor and from [the datasheet](http://files.andymark.com/CIM-motor-curve.pdf) it looks like it can output around 300W.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a site that referred to CIM as a *Controlled [Induction Motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor)*. Confirmed by [CIM at The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CIM)

It's entirely possible that the other answer is correct, as [this datasheet](https://andymark-weblinc.netdna-ssl.com/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTgvMTEvMjcvMDkvMzUvMjQvZWQxMzQxZjktNjg1My00Yzc2LTk5YTAtN2QyNDlmMWFhOGUzL2FtLTAyNTUgQ0lNIE1vdG9yIExheW91dC5wZGYiXV0/am-0255%20CIM%20Motor%20Layout.pdf?sha=816b33262672ebf2) has *CCL Industrial Motor Limited (CIM)* at the bottom.

Comment: I can confirm that in the context of FIRST Robotics Competition, CIM motor is likely not Controlled Induction Motor, as they are DC motors and not induction motors that we use. Controlled Induction Motor may be correct in other contexts, though.